# AsyncUserToken class is missing in SocketAsyncEventArgs sample: How to make the sample works?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I am working on TCP multithread server and client. I found some codes from Microsoft websites:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx

However I got the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'AsyncUserToken' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I cant find what namespace to include even I searched it on Google, here are those I currently have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6):

The `AsyncUserToken` class **is not part of the .NET framework**. It looks like it has been forgotten in the [Microsoft sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx).

You can create yourself the `AsyncUserToken` class with a `Socket` property (corresponding to the socket used to perform the I/O operations) :

```
internal class AsyncUserToken
{
  public System.Net.Sockets.Socket Socket { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess I found something related:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22918/How-To-Use-the-SocketAsyncEventArgs-Class